# c# Casting object to enum wont work

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, converters

I've got this xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Source=Typ, Converter={StaticResource ColorConv}}">
```

Typ is an Enum, this one:

```
public enum LogEintragTyp { Debug, Fehler, Debug2, Warnung, Analyse, User }
```

I've got a Converter that converts that type to a color. Heres a part of it:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(LogEintragTyp), typeof(Color))]
public class LogTypToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value.GetType() == typeof(LogEintragTyp)))
            throw new Exception("Wrong type!");

        LogEintragTyp sv = (LogEintragTyp)value;
```

The objects that are bound to this template are ALWAYS "LogEintragTyp" values. However it always throws the exception there.

When I debug this in Visual Studio it says "value" is this:

[image: Wrong Type]

So it says "value" contains "Typ".
But when I look at the from the debugger on mouseover correctly casted value it says this (at the bottom):

[image]

"Debug" which is a value that I am looking for... But when I move the debugger to that line to actually let the program execute the conversion, it says invalid cast exception. Why isnt there a "LogEintragTyp" in the "value" object but the string "Typ" which is the name of the value that I'm actually looking for and the debugger is also seeing but the executing program isnt?

Comment: you can't box cast a string into an enum you need to use Enum.TryParse

Comment: It looks like `value` is a `string`.  And `sv` is just showing you the default value before it is set by the cast, in the debugger.

Comment: When you write `{Binding Source=Typ, ...}` the source object of the binding is just the string `"Typ"`. You probably want to bind to some object with a public `Typ` property, and write the Binding like this: `{Binding Path=Typ, ...}`, or just `{Binding Typ, ...}`.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking here without telling us what `Typ` is supposed to be. Is it a property of an object?

Comment: Exactly right clemens. Yes, Typ is a property of the object a template gets bound to. The main object "LogEintrag" has a "LogEintragTyp" called "Typ". Thats what I wanted to bind to here. Your answer was right, I needed to use "Path=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want to bind to the `Typ` property of some object, so your Binding should use `Path` instead of `Source`:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Path=Typ, Converter={StaticResource ColorConv}}">
```

Or

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Typ, Converter={StaticResource ColorConv}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

As comments have pointed out, your `value` is a string. Try this:

```
LogEintragTyp result;
if (Enum.TryParse((string)value, true, out result))
{
    return some color based on 'result';
}

return something else;
```

---

**EDIT**

The answer from @Clemens is clearly the right one, given the original intent. But if you want to display hardcoded values from XAML, using `Source=some-string` is one way to do it, with the above changes to the converter. Not exactly type-safe, though. You can also use the actual enum members, as follows:

```
public enum LogType { Good, Bad, Ugly }
```

XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:LogTypeToColorConverter x:Key="Converter" />
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Source={x:Static local:LogType.Good}, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Source={x:Static local:LogType.Bad}, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Source={x:Static local:LogType.Ugly}, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The `Convert` method:

```
if (value.GetType() != typeof(LogType))
    throw new Exception("Wrong type!");

switch ((LogType)value)
{
    case LogType.Good: return Brushes.Green;
    case LogType.Bad: return Brushes.Red;
    case LogType.Ugly: return Brushes.Orange;
    default: return Brushes.Black;
}
```

...which ends up like this:

[image]

Comment: The actual problem is not that the value produced by the Binding is a string and should be parsed (`Typ` isn't even a value of the enum), but that the binding expression is wrongly written.

Comment: Yep, thats it, clemens.